# Convert list of dates and times to cron format (java)

Tags: java, spring, cron

I've been struggling with searching for information for half a day and I can't find anything at all

The input is a list with date and time (Examples: Input: "2022-01-25T08:00:00" "2022-01-25T08:30:00" )

on the output, you need to get them in cron format. (Output: "0 0/30 8-9 * * *" )
Please tell me how to get this result

Comment: Why would `"2022-01-25T08:00:00" "2022-01-25T08:30:00"` translate to `"0 0/30 8-9 * * *"`? Even if we ignore the date, I would expect  `"0 0/30 8 * * *"`

Comment: More details are needed.  Why are you ignoring the date?  Do you have to use a ‘step’ value (`/30`)?

Comment: Full task - "develop a Java mechanism for converting a list of dates with time in cron". The example that I gave is just an example for understanding, unfortunately I made a mistake and the example is incorrect